# reportlab low performance

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm using **reportlab** to convert some big library (plain text in Russian) into pdf format.
When the original file is small enough (say, about 10-50 kB), it works fine. But if I'm trying to convert big texts (above 500kB) it takes lot of time to reportlab to proceed.
Does anyone knows what could be the problem?

```
BYTES_TO_READ = 10000 

def go(text):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("output.pdf")
    Story = [Spacer(1, 2*inch)]
    style = styles["Normal"]
    p = Paragraph(text, style)
    Story.append(p)
    doc.build(Story)

def get_text_from_file():
    source_file = open("book.txt", "r")
    text = source_file.read(BYTES_TO_READ)
    source_file.close()
    return text

go(get_text_from_file())
```

So, when I try to set the `BYTES_TO_READ` variable to more than 200-300 thousands (i.e., just to see what happening, not reading the full book, just some part of it) - it takes HUGE amount of time

Comment: Disk IO?  Implementation?  Processor bound?  Without code there's no way to know why your approach is slow.

Comment: Nobody can help without further facts, code etc. Nobody can guess what you are actually doing and how...

Comment: BTR = 10000  

def go(text):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("output.pdf")
    Story = [Spacer(1, 2*inch)]
    style = styles["Normal"]
    p = Paragraph(text, style)
    Story.append(p)
    doc.build(Story)

def get_text_from_file():
    source_file = open("book.txt", "r")
    text = source_file.read(BTR)
    source_file.close()
    return text

go(get_text_from_file())
</pre>


So, when I try to set the BTR (bytes to read) variable to more than 200-300 thousands (i.e., just to see what happening, not reading the full book, just some part of it) - it takes HUGE amount of time

Comment: Sorry for previous comment (couldn't find how to format the code), so I puted a code here

http://snipplr.com/view/67078/reportlab-low-performance/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in my experience, reportlab's performance sucks unless you really tweak your usage.  it gets the job done, so it's great and I always use it... but it uses a lot of memory, cpu ( i never measured disk-io, but i wouldn't be surprised ).

i often use it for making "certificates" , where I plot some custom text on top of a PDF background.  doing 2-3 pages is a few seconds, but a 30 page document takes 10+ minutes.

i never looked into why this happens, i've always had more important things to do.  but the reportlab list has lots of stories from people on how to drop from 12mins to 3mins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me preface by saying that I don't have much experience with reportlab at all. This is just a general suggestion. It also does not deal with exactly how you should be parsing and formatting the text you are reading into proper structures. I am just continuing to use the `Paragraph` class to write text.

In terms of performance, I think your problem is related to trying to read a huge string once, and passing that huge string as a single paragraph to reportlab. If you think about it, what paragraph is really 500k bytes?

What you would probably want to do is read in smaller chunks, and build up your document:

```py
def go_chunked(limit=500000, chunk=4096):

    BYTES_TO_READ = chunk

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("output.pdf")
    Story = [Spacer(1, 2*inch)]
    style = styles["Normal"]

    written = 0

    with open("book.txt", "r") as source_file:
        while written < limit:
            text = source_file.read(BYTES_TO_READ)
            if not text:
                break
            p = Paragraph(text, style)
            Story.append(p)
            written += BYTES_TO_READ

    doc.build(Story)
```

When processing a total of 500k bytes:

```
%timeit go_chunked(limit=500000, chunk=4096)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.88 s per loop

%timeit go(get_text_from_file())
1 loops, best of 3: 64.1 s per loop
```

Again, obviously this is just splitting your text into arbitrary paragraphs being the size of the  `BYTES_TO_READ` value, but its not much different than one huge paragraph. Ultimately, you might want to parse the text you are reading into a buffer, and determine your own paragraphs, or just split on lines if that is the format of your original source:

```
def go_lines(limit=500000):

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("output.pdf")
    Story = [Spacer(1, 2*inch)]
    style = styles["Normal"]

    written = 0

    with open("book.txt", "r") as source_file:
        while written < limit:
            text = source_file.readline()
            if not text:
                break
            text = text.strip()
            p = Paragraph(text, style)
            Story.append(p)
            written += len(text)

    doc.build(Story)
```

Performance:

```
%timeit go_lines()
1 loops, best of 3: 1.46 s per loop
```

Comment: Wow!Great! Worked very god for me!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Very welcome. Thanks for adding your code example, which allowed me to answer :-)  Dont forget to hit the checkmark if this solved your question.